# Javascript Call Stack / Execution Context reference

Tags: javascript

When I executed the following javascript, I was expecting b()'s console log to print undefined. (Since I did not declare name).

```
function b(){
    console.log(name);
}

function a(){
    var name = "rupesh";
    b();
}

var name = "Demo";
a();
```

> Expected Output: Undefined
>
> Actual output:  Demo

I've been reading on Global execution context, Execution context of Javascript. It's been mentioned that the execution context will look for Global execution context.

But if i understand right, function a() and function b() are executed in a stack. How does it go back to execution context (In datastructure perspective this doesn't happen).

Kinda confused. Please explain how this works!

Comment: Hoisting. http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I executed the following javascript, I was expecting b()'s console log to print undefined. (Since I did not declare name).

Technically `name` ***is*** declared. That's so called *hoisting*. So, the runtimer "catch" all the `var` declarations and put them on top of the function (in your case, as it's not inside a function, they're attached to the global namespace). So, it'd be like this:

```
var name;
function b(){
   console.log(name);
}
...
```

Now, when `a()` is called the `name` variable has value assigned, in this case `"Demo"`.

Inside `function a () {...}` you assign a variable called `name` again, but as this has `var` before it, that `name` doesn't change the global `name` (I think you have already figured that out, since you'd expected `name` to be `undefined`).

Finally, when `b()` is invoked inside `a()`, it looks to the global `name` variable assigned with the `"Demo"` value.

Just to show the whole picture, that's how the runtime "sees" your code:

```
var name;

function b(){
  console.log(name);
 }

 function a(){
   var name = "rupesh";
   b();
 }

 name = "Demo";
 a();
```

Comment: Amazing couldn't explain any better